# SpaCy model won't load in AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, spacy

Has anyone gotten SpaCy 2.0 to work in AWS Lambda? I have everything zipped and packaged correctly, since I can get a generic string to return from my lambda function if I test it. But when I do the simple function below to test, it stalls for about 10 seconds and then returns empty, and I don't get any error messages. I did set my Lambda timeout at 60 seconds so that isn't the problem.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') #model package included

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    doc = nlp(u'They are')
    msg = doc[0].lemma_
    return msg
```

When I load the model package without using it, it also returns empty, but if I comment it out it sends me the string as expected, so it has to be something about loading the model.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') #model package included

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    msg = 'message returned'
    return msg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Knew it was probably going to be something simple. The answer is that there wasn't enough allocated memory to run the Lambda function - I found that I had to minimally increase it to near the max 2816 MB to get the example above to work. It is notable that before last month it wasn't possible to go this high:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/aws-lambda-doubles-maximum-memory-capacity-for-lambda-functions/

I turned it up to the max of 3008 MB to handle more text and everything seems to work just fine now.

Comment: how did u get spacy module to install in an AWS Lambda?

Comment: I installed it on an Amazon AMI instance on EC2, then copied the package and dependencies into a local deployment package with my lambda function and zipped it for deployment (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)

Comment: The spacy install without a model is 290mb. How did you get it below 250mb?

Comment: Spacy 2.0? I can't remember what dependencies it needed but it was much smaller than 250mb.

Comment: @JAB did u figure out how to get it install in an AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 8):

To optimize model load you have to store it on S3, and download it using your own script to tmp folder in lambda and then load it into spacy from it.

It will take 5 seconds to download it from S3 and run. The good optimization here is to keep model on warm container and check if it was already downloaded. On warm container code takes 0.8 seconds to run.

Here is the link to the code and package with example:
https://github.com/ryfeus/lambda-packs/blob/master/Spacy/source2.7/index.py

```
import spacy
import boto3
import os


def download_dir(client, resource, dist, local='/tmp', bucket='s3bucket'):
    paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
    for result in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Delimiter='/', Prefix=dist):
        if result.get('CommonPrefixes') is not None:
            for subdir in result.get('CommonPrefixes'):
                download_dir(client, resource, subdir.get('Prefix'), local, bucket)
        if result.get('Contents') is not None:
            for file in result.get('Contents'):
                if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(local + os.sep + file.get('Key'))):
                     os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(local + os.sep + file.get('Key')))
                resource.meta.client.download_file(bucket, file.get('Key'), local + os.sep + file.get('Key'))

def handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    if (os.path.isdir("/tmp/en_core_web_sm")==False):
        download_dir(client, resource, 'en_core_web_sm', '/tmp','ryfeus-spacy')
    spacy.util.set_data_path('/tmp')
    nlp = spacy.load('/tmp/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0')
    doc = nlp(u'Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion')
    for token in doc:
        print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_)
    return 'finished'
```

P.S. To package spacy within AWS Lambda you have to strip shared libraries.

Comment: Can you share a link on how to "strip shared libraries"? -Thanks

Comment: @ItayLivni Did you figure out who to strip the libraries?

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan the best way is to strip out all of the unused languages within spacy as these take a lot of room in the package. I created a gist you can use to do this: https://gist.github.com/jshhrrsn/5377b9dd282ef51f5564f1347a7d5aef

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was `cd`ing into `<YOUR_ENV>/lib/Python<VERSION>/site-packages/ and removing the language models I didn't need. For example, I only needed the English language model so once in my own site-packages directory I just needed to run a`ls -d */ | grep -v en | xargs rm -rf`, and then zip up the contents to get it under Lambda's limits.